# Enter null value in number field in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, null, int

I am trying to enter null value if incoming value is less than 0 in Number field in Oracle table. I tried this way but its giving me invalid column index. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you

```
if (getNepID() > 0 )
{
   cstmt.setInt(9,this.getNepID());
}else{
   cstmt.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.NULL);
}
```

Comment: It is clearly issue with the number of parameters in the SQL Prepared statement. Check the SQL statement that is being parsed and seee if indeed has 10 or more parameters. Also change the setNull statement to `cstmt.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);`

Comment: @Cybernate: 9 or more parameters. JDBC starts at 1 rather than 0.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thx for correction.. I get confused with the 0 based indexes and 1 based indexes. :)

Comment: @Cybernate: Could you move your comment down to an answer so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I have posted my comment as the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly issue with the number of parameters in the SQL Prepared statement.

Check the SQL statement that is being parsed and seee if indeed has 9 or more parameters.

Also change the setNull statement to `cstmt.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);`